# Restart after installing ubuntu on dell inspiron only boots into initramfs terminal

Tags: boot, 16.04, dell, initramfs

I'm trying to install ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64 on my Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop. I used a usb stick with the mounted image to install, but after restarting it only gets as far as the initramfs terminal and I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Mounted image? did you make it bootable?

Comment: yeah I used universal USB installer by pendrivelinux.com